# Send different types of messages over socket

Tags: c#, serialization, tcp, rsa

I have a tcp client that sends different types of messages and I'm a little confused how to make that work. First the client sends a string (converted into byte[]) and that works fine but then I'm trying to send a serialized object and I don't know how to do that and how to get the server to understand that the message isn't a string.
The object I'm trying to send is the public key of RSA algorithm

```
 IFormatter formatter=new BinaryFormatter();
 formatter.Serialize(client.GetStream(),RSAParameterskeyinfo);
```

but I don't know how to get the server to understand that this message isn't a byte[].

Comment: Edit your question to show how you are serializing and sending you object as well as how you are attempting to read it in

Comment: The simpler thing would be to just use WCF, which will do all the work for you.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yeah it's a solution too but maybe he don't have access to .NET 4 and WCF. (I had this problem)

Comment: I don't have access to .Net 4 are there any other ways?

Comment: @user3475840 My answer doesn't help?

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? WCF has been available since .NET 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

To make your server understand which type of object he will have to compute you must share a dll between the client and the server. The hard part here is to handle version of this dll (when you make change on the object you want to share between the client and the server you will have to update the dll on each side)

Then use a `BinaryFormatter` to serialize/deserialize your object.
First on the client side serialize your object with something like :

```
MyMessage msg = new MyMessage("My custom message")
byte[] data;
using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(ms, msg);
    data = ms.ToArray();
    /*
     * Send to stream
     */
}
```

Then on the server size you have to deserialize it like :

```
/*
 * Get the network stream
 */
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MyMessage msg = (MyMessage) formatter.Deserialize(myStream);
```

As they share the same dll, each side know the `Message` object.

For more informations about `BinaryFormatter` see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx